# jtextfield increment by 1 starting from B3001 when click add button in swing

Tags: java, swing

My bill number(using jtextfield) must auto increment by 1 after clicking submit button. I need sequtenial values in format like B3001,B3002, and so on.... Kindly plz help me

```
public static class SequentialNumber
{
       private static int currentNumber=3000;
       public static String GetNextNumber()
       {
            currentNumber++;
            return "B"+currentNumber;
       }
}
public Printbill() {


    contentPane1 = new JPanel();
    contentPane1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    contentPane1.setLayout(null);



    dcfield = new JTextField();

    dcfield.setBounds(553, 109, 86, 20);
    contentPane1.add(dcfield);
    dcfield.setColumns(10);
    String ContractNo=SequentialNumber.GetNextNumber();
    dcfield.setText(ContractNo);
    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          Printbill p=new Printbill();
          dispose();
            p.setVisible(true);
            SequentialNumber s=new SequentialNumber();
            String stt=s.GetNextNumber();
           dcfield.setText(stt);
        }
    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Printbill extends JFrame {
    public static class SequentialNumber {
        private static int currentNumber = 3000;

        public static String GetNextNumber() {
            currentNumber++;
            return "B" + currentNumber;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Printbill();
            }
        });
    }

    public Printbill() {

        JPanel contentPane1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        contentPane1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        final JTextField dcfield = new JTextField();

        contentPane1.add(dcfield);
        dcfield.setColumns(10);
        String contractNo = SequentialNumber.GetNextNumber();
        dcfield.setText(contractNo);
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
        contentPane1.add(btnAdd, BorderLayout.EAST);
        getContentPane().add(contentPane1);
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String stt = SequentialNumber.GetNextNumber();
                dcfield.setText(stt);
            }
        });
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

What's wrong with your code:

- You've tried to use absolute layout (`setLayout(null)`). It's bad practice, so I've change the layout to BorderLayout. After that I've added `pack()` to set the appropriate size for window (this method works only with a non-null layout). For more information read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).
- I've changed action listener so it only update text field.
- `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is required for correct start of Swing application. All widget initialisation/manipulation must be performed in Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` allows to call a piece of code in EDT.

Comment: thank you sir..its working..what is the difference between swingutilities.invokelater and Eventqueue.invokelater

Comment: There is no difference between these methods. By the way. If my answer was helpfull please upvote it and/or mark it as correct.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy, An answer should include an explanation of what the original problem  was and what you did to fix the problem, not just a core dump of working code.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for suggestion.